# Redirecting and using a QueryString to pass values

Tags: javascript

I want to create a contacts page,

I have the following code:

```
<div>
    <h4 class="item-name" style="line-height: 0.5;">#:Name# #:Surname#</h4>
<div>
```

There aretwo more values(contactNumber and Email)

In the first view I only show the name, the I want to redirect to other page on click.

something like.

`<a href="contactActionView?id=.....">`

Should I only pass ID or can I pass the name, surname, mobile and email through the `<a href="contactActionView?id=.....">` query string, I would prefer to do that.

`<a href="contactActionView?id=#:name=#:number=#:email#">`

Then In the next view/window just display it in `<p>` tag's.

So my Question is how will I pass the values using queryString?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what exactly you're asking for help with.  The usual query string format is like this: `http://www.example.com/?name=John&surname=Friend&number=333-444-5555&email=whatever@foo.com` and then you parse out each separate parameter in the receiving end.  The query string starts with `?` and then you use `tag=value` and use `&` to separate each separate parameter.

Comment: I think that I what I needed. I need help to see if my code try was any good?

Comment: What code?  I don't see any code in your question, just placeholder HTML.

Comment: @jfriend00 the redirect part????? `<a href="contactActionView?id=#:name=#:number=#:email#">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var id = document.querySelector('input[name="id"]').value;
var name = document.querySelector('input[name="name"]').value;
var number = document.querySelector('input[name="number"]').value;
var email = document.querySelector('input[name="email"]').value;

window.location = "http://urltowitchyouwantotoredirect?id=" + id + "&name=" + name + "&number=" + number + "&email=" + email;
```

without window.location it should be like this:

```
function GetUrl()
{
     var id = document.querySelector('input[name="id"]').value;
     var name = document.querySelector('input[name="name"]').value;
     var number = document.querySelector('input[name="number"]').value;
     var email = document.querySelector('input[name="email"]').value;

     document.querySelector("#myhyperlink").href = "http://urltowitchyouwantotoredirect?id=" + id + "&name=" + name + "&number=" + number + "&email=" + email;
}
```

`<a id="myhyperlink"> Go</a>`

in each input you will need to make `onchange="GetUrl();"`

Comment: can I use <a> insted of window.location just a normal <a> tag?